# Dependency issue with spark-network-common_2.11/1.6.2

Tags: apache-spark

i am having following error when  I add following dependency in STS  I am getting errors

```
   <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Error is

Archive for required library:
      'C:/Users/Ravinder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-network-common_2.11/1.6.2/spark-network-common_2.11-1.6.2.jar'
       in project 'scalaDemo2'    cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file scalaDemo2 Build path   Build     Path Problem

### in STS scala library is pointing to 2.11.8

Does spark looks at scala version, in Spark installation I am not seeing a scala version config. please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is with a corrupted library, not a version mismatch.

A spark installation will be tied to either Scala 2.10 or 2.11.  Libraries are binary compatible within 2.11 so it shouldn't matter whether you are 2.11.8 or 2.11.6.

I'd suggest deleting everything under C:/Users/Ravinder/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-network-common_2.11 and see if when you try again it caches a correct file.

Comment: I though Maven clean would do that, I had scala 2.11 and going back to 2.10 thats where issues started However I had deleted all the project and recreated help me go further.  Thanks for your feedback